# Setting TFS pending changes default view to folder view

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

Got a question about viewing files in TFS (specifically, under Pending Changes).

I do NOT like the default flat file view that comes up when I open Pending Changes.  I want to set the default to folder view.  But I can't find any such setting anywhere.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Though MS officially replied that VS is lack of this feature, there's a workaround using macro. I found it yesterday and also added it in this posting:

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/520449/window-pending-changes-does-not-remember-flat-or-hierarchical-view

FYI, this is the workaround that I added there:

---

(I am using VS 2008 but this trick may work for VS 2010. The details below are for VS 2008.)

A startup macro can be used to workaround this issue. Follow these steps:

1. Open VS, make sure that Pending Changes pane is showing in Flat View and close it.
2. Run Tools > Macros > Record TemporaryMacro.
3. Select View > Other Windows > Pending Changes. Then hit Folder View button in Pending Changes.
4. Finish macro recording and open Macros IDE (Tools > Macros > Macros IDE...).
5. There should be TemporaryMacro() recorded under RecodingModule macro. Copy the contents of the subroutine. In my case, it was:

   DTE.ExecuteCommand ("View.TfsPendingChanges")

   DTE.Commands.Raise("{FFE1131C-8EA1-4D05-9728-34AD4611BDA9}", 4804, Customin, Customout)
6. In the Macros IDE, go to EnvironmentEvents. In the dropdowns at the top of the editor which look like Types/Members selector of VS code editor, select "DTEEvents" and "OnStartupComplete" respectively.
7. Event handler DTEEvents_OnStartupComplete() should have been generated. Paste the copied macro contents from step 5 above into the new event handler.
8. Save changes and that's it.

Steps above may look complicated but it's nothing more than recording pane opening and button clicking action as a macro and registering it in the startup event handler.

Hope this helps.

---

Answer (score 0):

I'm using VS 2010 with all updates applied., you didn't indicate which version of TFS you have.

I opened the pending changes window (View > Other Windows > Pending Changes).  Then I clicked on the "change to folder view" button and closed the window.

When I reopened the pending changes window, it kept my settings and showed it using the folder view.

Comment: Yeah, I'm using VS2010.  My bad.

That did not work. It maintained it after I closed and reopened the pending changes window, but it did NOT maintain it after closing and reopening TFS, which is what I want. I want it to open in folder view EVERY time. I don't want to have to click Folder View every single time I open pending changes.

Comment: @Ray K: what do you mean "closing and reopening TFS"?  Are you talking about using the TFS Client outside of visual studio?

Comment: I mean turning off VS2010 and restarting it.  I want it in folder view from the get-go.

Comment: @Ray K: Interesting.  Just tried that and it reset like you have said.  My guess is that your SOL. ;)  Sorry this wasn't helpful.

Comment: Yeah, I figured as much.  Not a huge deal.  It's just an annoyance, nothing more.  Thanks for trying, anyway.